# Set Carousel to slide automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple carousel.

I'd like to make it slide automatically instead of having to click the arrows.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/vbcL9npo/

```js
carousel = (function(){

  // Read necessary elements from the DOM once
  var box = document.querySelector('.carouselbox');
  var next = box.querySelector('.next');
  var prev = box.querySelector('.prev');

  // Define the global counter, the items and the 
  // current item 
  var counter = 0;
  var items = box.querySelectorAll('.content li');
  var amount = items.length;
  var current = items[0];

  box.classList.add('active');

  // navigate through the carousel

  function navigate(direction) {

    // hide the old current list item 
    current.classList.remove('current');
    
    // calculate th new position
    counter = counter + direction;

    // if the previous one was chosen
    // and the counter is less than 0 
    // make the counter the last element,
    // thus looping the carousel
    if (direction === -1 && 
        counter < 0) { 
      counter = amount - 1; 
    }

    // if the next button was clicked and there 
    // is no items element, set the counter 
    // to 0
    if (direction === 1 && 
        !items[counter]) { 
      counter = 0;
    }

    // set new current element 
    // and add CSS class
    current = items[counter];
    current.classList.add('current');
  }

  // add event handlers to buttons
  next.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    navigate(1);
  });
  prev.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    navigate(-1);
  });

  // show the first element 
  // (when direction is 0 counter doesn't change)
  navigate(0);

})();
```

```css
.carouselbox {
      font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 100px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 1em;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #ccc;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .content {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .content li {
      font-size: 100px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 2;
    }


    .active {
      height: 130px;
    }
    .carouselbox button {
      border: none;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .active button {
      visibility: visible;
    } 
    .offscreen {
      position: absolute;
      left: -2000px;
    }

    .active .buttons {
      padding: 5px 0;
      background: #eee;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 10;
      position: relative;
    }
    .active li {
      position: absolute;
      top: 130px;

      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(0);
      transition: 1s;
    }
    .active li.current {
      top: 30px;

      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1);
      transition: 1s;
    }
```

```html
<div class="carouselbox">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="prev">
       ◀ <span class="offscreen">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="next">
      <span class="offscreen">Next</span> ▶ 
    </button>
  </div>
  <ol class="content">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: `setInterval(function() { navigate(1) }, 3000);`? Where `3000` would be your interval

Comment: @GeoffJames `setTimout` will execute once, you need `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks @Stan. I know, I got a bit happy with the keyboard and changed it when I'd realised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval`. Save it as a variable and then you can clear it later if you want auto to stop.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vbcL9npo/1/

```
var carousel = (function(){

  // Read necessary elements from the DOM once
  var box = document.querySelector('.carouselbox');
  var next = box.querySelector('.next');
  var prev = box.querySelector('.prev');

  // Define the global counter, the items and the 
  // current item 
  var counter = 0;
  var items = box.querySelectorAll('.content li');
  var amount = items.length;
  var current = items[0];

  box.classList.add('active');

  // navigate through the carousel

  function navigate(direction) {

    // hide the old current list item 
    current.classList.remove('current');

    // calculate th new position
    counter = counter + direction;

    // if the previous one was chosen
    // and the counter is less than 0 
    // make the counter the last element,
    // thus looping the carousel
    if (direction === -1 && 
        counter < 0) { 
      counter = amount - 1; 
    }

    // if the next button was clicked and there 
    // is no items element, set the counter 
    // to 0
    if (direction === 1 && 
        !items[counter]) { 
      counter = 0;
    }

    // set new current element 
    // and add CSS class
    current = items[counter];
    current.classList.add('current');
  }

  // add event handlers to buttons
  next.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    navigate(1);
  });
  prev.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    navigate(-1);
  });

  // show the first element 
  // (when direction is 0 counter doesn't change)
  navigate(0);

    var interval = setInterval(function () { navigate(1) }, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: That's amazing! Now I just need to find a way to create a pause button :-)

Comment: There are some things you can do, for example introduce variable `isPaused` and check if it is `false` before doing `navigate(1)`. You can also do `clearInterval(interval)` but it will destroy the interval and you will need to start it again.